# How to return to a specific point int the code without having to use goto?

Tags: c#

So I wrote a lottery program.
The program works as the following:

1. the user inputs 6 numbers ranging from 1 to 46.
2. the program chooses 6 numbers ranging from 1 to 46.
3. the program compares the arrays for matching numbers.
4. the program shows the user how many matching number he got right and also if he won the lottery or not.

end

now , I want to add an option to the user , if the user wants to try again he can just press Y and the program will jump him to the point where he inputs numbers.

But , I don't know how to achieve that without using goto, I don't want to use goto because I know it's bad practice to use it.

Would love to get some recommendations.

I know that I am still missing the N portion of the code, but I just wanted to show what I've tried so far.

char tryAgain;

```
        if (gamelost || gamewon == true)
        {
            tryAgain = 'Y';
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to try again? Y/N");
            tryAgain = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (tryAgain == 'Y')
            {
                goto gameAgain;
            }

            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hint: use a loop. Now try something yourself.

Comment: I don't see how I can use a loop to just return a user to the beginning of a code..

Comment: Think about what a loop does. When you reach the end of a loop, what does it do? You go back to the start of the loop! Make use of this behaviour to achieve what you want.

Comment: You got it the wrong way around. If you really need to go to a point in the code you would have to use a goto. But: You should write your code in such a way that this doesn't occur. Use a semantic loop, ie `while not done do..`

Comment: I think I am forming an idea, will update with results.

Comment: If you don't want a loop you can also try a state machine. You just set the state to the input state. Technically you will need a loop around the state machine.

Comment: Update: I've put my entire program in a do while loop and created another bool variable that changes from true to false depending on what the user is going to choose, if it's true than the program loops , if not , the program ends. Thanks for giving me a push in the right direction :)

Comment: You need to use a loop with `if/else` containing `continue` and `break/return` that match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop. You need to check the only condition upon which you exit the loop. Note that this code doesn't sanitize user's input.

```
using static System.Console;

void do_lottery()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Write("Enter 6 digits, divided by comma: ");
        var input = ReadLine();
        var user_numbers = input.Split(",").Select(n => int.Parse(n));
        var numbers_to_guess = new[] { 6, 23, 12, 46, 8, 2 };
        if (user_numbers.All(n => numbers_to_guess.Any(z => z == n)))
        {
            WriteLine("You won!");
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLine("You lose!");
        }
        Write("Do you wanna play once again? (Y/N): ");
        var answer = ReadLine().ToUpper();
        if (answer != "Y") break; //Exit loop
    }
    WriteLine("Lottery finished.");
}
```

Comment: @ShlomiU Also, note that if user (according to my example) enters `2,2,2,2,2,2`, then he'll win a game! LOL!  This means that you need to develop special logic to compare user's input with numbers to guess.